# Localhost PHP works but not within HTML

Tags: php, macos, localhost

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10 and I'm having a problem running PHP on my Localhost here.  It works fine when I load a PHP file directly in the browser (using HTTP localhost):

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

But it doesn't work when I embed the same PHP within HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Do I maybe have something configured wrong? Is there something I should check in my apache/php setup files?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you're loading from a .html file? php won't get invoked unless you TELL the webserver to treat .html files as php. If you're loading from a file:// url, then, php will never get invoked either. It's not your browser's job to act as a webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the file to be parsed by PHP, your file needs to have a .php extension.

In this case, instead of file.html it should be called file.php

The html will render without any parsing, while your php code will parse without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue to load your PHP over HTTP, from a server that has PHP installed and configured, using a file that the server will parse for PHP (which usually means having a `.php` file extension).